# Error: suitable constructor found and cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, subclass

I am currently creating a code that has a subclass which will inherit the data fields and methods of a superclass. The subclass will also have an additional field but I wanted to start with one field.

I am using an input file called birds.csv that has 4 columns. I want to add 5th coumn with 10 rows of data which I already did.

I am using that subclass to get and set the methods of the field and initialize it.

I currently have 4 errors with my code and I really need help with what I need to fix.

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestingCode {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   //error checking for commandline input
      if(args.length != 1){
         System.out.println("Please enter at least one input file into the argument.");
         //terminates the program if more than 1 is entered
         System.exit(1);
      }

      String csvFile = args[0];
      String line = "";
      String cvsSplitBy = ",";

      List<HawaiiNativeForestBirds>  listofBirds = new ArrayList<HawaiiNativeForestBirds>();
      try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] bird = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            HawaiiNativeForestBirds Hawaiinbird = new HawaiiNativeForestBirdsWithMoreData(bird[0],bird[1],bird[2],Integer.valueOf(bird[3]),bird[4]);
            listofBirds.add(Hawaiinbird);
         }
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      HawaiiNativeForestBirds[]  hbirds=new        HawaiiNativeForestBirds[listofBirds.size()];
      System.out.println("index   " + "    element   ");  
      int i=0;
      for (HawaiiNativeForestBirds hbird:hbirds){
         i++;
         System.out.println(i+"            "+hbird);
      }

      hbirds= listofBirds.toArray(new HawaiiNativeForestBirds[listofBirds.size()]);

      System.out.println("index   " + "name   "+ "   Scientific Name     "+ "        Color     " +       "      Population");        
      i=0;
      for (HawaiiNativeForestBirds hbird:hbirds){
         i++;
         System.out.println(i+"   "+hbird.toString());
      }

      hbirds= listofBirds.toArray(new HawaiiNativeForestBirds[listofBirds.size()]);

      System.out.println("index   " + "name   "+ "   Scientific Name     "+ "        Color     " +       "      Population");        
      i=0;
      for (HawaiiNativeForestBirds hbird:hbirds){
         i++;
         System.out.println(i+"   "+hbird.toString2());
      }

      hbirds= listofBirds.toArray(new HawaiiNativeForestBirds[listofBirds.size()]);

      System.out.println("index   " + "name   "+ "   Scientific Name     "+ "        Color     " +       "      Population" +       "      Author");        
      i=0;
      for (HawaiiNativeForestBirds hbird:hbirds){
         i++;
         System.out.println(i+"   "+hbird.toString3());
      }
   } 
}

class HawaiiNativeForestBirds {
   protected String name;
   protected String scientificname;
   protected String color;
   protected Integer population;

   public HawaiiNativeForestBirds(){
   }

   public HawaiiNativeForestBirds(String name, String scientificname,
        String color, Integer population) {
      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.scientificname = scientificname;
      this.color = color;
      this.population = population;
   }

   // getters and setters hidden

   public String toString() {
      String output = name + "     " + scientificname + "             " + color + "           " + population;
      return output;
   }

   public String toString2() {
      population = population + 1;
      String output = name.toUpperCase() + "     " + scientificname.toUpperCase() + "             "+ color.toUpperCase() + "           " + population;
      return output;
   }
}
```

Class `HawaiiNativeForestBirdsWithMoreData`:

```
class HawaiiNativeForestBirdsWithMoreData extends HawaiiNativeForestBirds { 

    private String author;

    public HawaiiNativeForestBirdsWithMoreData(){  
    }

    public HawaiiNativeForestBirdsWithMoreData(String name, String scientificname,
        String color, Integer population, String author) {
        super(name, scientificname, color, population);
        this.author = author;
    }  

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String toString3() {
        population = population + 1;
        String output = name.toUpperCase() + "     " + scientificname.toUpperCase() + "             " + color.toUpperCase() + "           " + population + "           " +author.toUpperCase();
        return output;
    }
}
```

Here are my errors:

```
TestingCode.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
         System.out.println(i+"   "+hbird.toString3());
                                         ^
  symbol:   method toString3()
  location: variable hbird of type HawaiiNativeForestBirds
1 error
```

Here is my input file :
[image: birds.csv]

Comment: You don't have a constructor defined which accepts the parameters you're passing. Look at your constructors, and determine which one you think should be getting called

Comment: so which one should I change to fix all that? Use HawaiiNativeForestBirdsWithMoreData Instead?

Comment: The constructor tells you what parameters it is expecting, and how many of them there are. e.g. `HawaiiNativeForestBirds(String name, String scientificname, String color, Integer population)`. If you're passing in something that's not the `name`, `scientificName`, `color`, or `population` (*in that order*) then your code will not work. Pay attention to the line numbers in the error messages, and lookup the errors that you dont understand.

Comment: managed to fix the issue but I only have 1 error remaining. issue is I can't use tostring3 but when I try tostring2 it works but doesn't show my last column (author) and it's values for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may not be with your constructor by how you declared the instance of a bird. You have, the constructor as (String, String, String, Int, String), but your data is in the order (String, String, Int, String). Double check the order in your csv file and make sure it matches the order in which you are passing in the parameters.

Edit: After checking the csv file. the population is the 4th item in the list, so

```
 HawaiiNativeForestBirds Hawaiinbird= new HawaiiNativeForestBirds(bird[0],bird[1],Integer.valueOf(bird[2]), bird[3]);
```

Also, as pointed out, there is a 5th parameter being passed in so you'll need to update the constructor to accommodate for it.

Edit for last error:

The data type of the array does not much what is needed to use the toString3() method. You'll only have access to toString() and toString2() while it is of type HawaiiNativeForestBirds even if the actual type contains toString3().

Comment: The constructor takes 4 arguments. You're passing in 5 arguments, as is the OP. That's the first problem.

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to pass 5 arguments

Comment: Alright ! I managed to fixed two problems which reduce everything and fixed the majority of the issue. Only 1 error remains ! I added that error on the top

Comment: HawaiiNativeForestBirds only has toString() and toString2. HawaiiNativeForestBirdsWithMoreData is needed to use toString3(). The array you're using to store the birds has the type of HawaiiNativeForestBirds so it can not access toString3() even if the actual object has the method.

Comment: @Brion Since your comment solves the issue, you should just update your answer to include that fix... `:)`

Comment: huh what should I do next? or what should I replace @Brion ?

Comment: @Siegfraud245 The method `toString3` does not exist on the class `HawaiiNativeForestBirds`. To use it, you'll have to cast to the sub-class type: `System.out.println(i + "   " + ((HawaiiNativeForestBirdsWithMoreData) hbird).toString3());`. Alternatively, you can change the type of your array.

Comment: Will all bird entries contain the 5th column? If so, then you can just change the declaration of HawaiiNativeForestBirds[]  hbirds to HawaiiNativeForestBirdsWithMoreData[] hbirds.

Comment: for the 2nd output where I will only show what is on data, since I added the 5th column, do I need to edit my HawaiiNativeForestBirds class or not?

Comment: Using the 3 toString() methods you have you can always display less data, but never more. So you shouldn't need to edit anything for now.